# Help looking for an 220V AC transformer replacement

Tags: ac, transformer, vintage, replacement

My old Philips MC-M250 stereo transformer has died after a power surge. I can't find spares so I'm looking for some compatible replacement.

I found a power board circuit in the [service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1233884/Philips-Mc-M250.html?page=17).

AC is 220V. From the power board 3 wires lead to the main board. I can't find output voltage. I assume it is 12V, but I'm not sure.

I would greatly appreciate any tips.

[image: CIRCUIT DIAGRAM - POWER BOARD]
[image: LAYOUT DIAGRAM - POWER BOARD]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 28 gives more clues.......................

[image]

Also with 15 A fuse on your page with the secondary, the VAR rating will be less than 250 VAR.

Comment: The first drawing shows the fuses as 3.15 amp, not 15 Amp.  However, that drawing doesn't match the second, as the second drawing and PCB photos, show a 120/230 V input selector switch.  The manual appears to cover several models.  It does give the power consumption as 60 Watts.

Comment: thanks Peter , my BER seems to be rising recently  and perhaps that's telling

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that. And a bit a beginner question, but what do you think, if I would find a 220V -> 16V transformer with only two wires output and connect it to 3.15 amp fuses? Is it worth trying?

Something like this:
https://www.lemona.lt/?page=item&i_id=58238

Comment: Or this:
https://goo.gl/GvXW31

Comment: I prefer the toroid but reduce fuse if possible to <3A or use a 2.8A PTC polyfuse (common).  But only try if you are sure the only problem is the XFMR and not a bunch of other things too,.  (Toroidinis(;  They sometimes use NTC or ICL surge limiters to protect power-on surges.  Check caps for bulges.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll try toroid. One more beginner question, as I don't have much experience with AC (all my hobby projects were with DC): from the transformer I will get 2 wires output. To the main board lead 3 wires. I assume that one of the wires is "neutral" and other two "active" (can be interconnected), but I'm not sure how to read the scheme. Any tip how to read it/connect? Thanks again for advises! :)