# How to reduce AC voltage from 17V to 15.8V?

Tags: voltage, ac, transformer

My old stereo's transformer has burnt out after a power surge and I'm trying to replace it.

I have **220V AC -> 17V AC** toroidal transformer available. In the schematic diagram I found it indicates that it should be **15.8V AC**. The fuse is rated for 3.15A.

What would be the best way to reduce the voltage?

[Related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355371/help-looking-for-an-220v-ac-transformer-replacement)

Comment: Leon beat me to it but yes. Remove part of the secondary winding. The voltage across a transformer is dependent on the winding ratio. The current, however, is something you want to take caution of as well.

Comment: This is related to your question here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355371/help-looking-for-an-220v-ac-transformer-replacement?rq=1

Comment: Is it crucial that the voltage be that precise? Bearing in mind the variation in voltage with transformer loading and indeed mains voltage itself?

Comment: @IanBland yes I think 17V is too high because after connecting it the stereo worked for a very short time and then the fuse has burnt out. Also one capacitor became very hot on the main board.

Comment: @Laurynas Capacitors should be able to handle a slightly larger voltage like this (they're usually at least 20% overrated), so that cap is most likely defective. You should replace it and any similar capacitors.

Comment: @JonathanS. thanks for an explanation - I will replace a capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this relates to your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355371/help-looking-for-an-220v-ac-transformer-replacement) that has a link to a set of schematic diagrams.

Firstly this unit requires a centre tapped transformer to generate the other voltage rail in the stereo.  You need three (or sometimes arranged as two independent windings and then needing four) output wires.

The natural variation in the supply voltage indicated in the service manual is about 15% depending on loading (full or standby) condition.  The voltage increase you are asking about is only a further 7% above nominal.  Most systems should be able to tolerate this extra supply voltage as the mains voltage may swing over 10% already (in Europe 220 to 240V).  In the case of a long extension cord or a mid winter heating peak the voltage may drop even lower so large variation in supply is a norm.

On [page 28](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1233884/Philips-Mc-M250.html?page=28#manual) of the service manual you can see the details of the voltage regulator circuits.  The rectified output voltage is specified at 21.7 and with an extra 7% that would be 23.2.  The capacitor is rated with a working voltage of 25V (see [page 53](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1233884/Philips-Mc-M250.html?page=53#manual)) and should still cope.  The voltage regulators should cope with the extra unless they are designed very near the margins.

Your bigger problem is that your new transformer may indicate 17V but might be 10 or 20% higher voltage under no load and this could exceed safe limits of the capacitors when in standby and the peak voltage is reached.

Removing turns from a transformer is a lot of work and you would have to remove them from both parts of a centre tapped coil (may be easy or lots of work depending on how they are wound on) to gain any benefit.

However on most toroidal transformers it is relatively easy to add turns through the hole and this could be used on the primary to reduce the secondary voltage.  You would have to add primary turns and connect them in series with your main input winding.  This requires more care with connections and insulation than working with the secondary winding.  If you want to try this you need to locate some mains insulated wire with 0.5A current capacity and pass 10 turns through the hole and measure the voltage say 8V.  Divide the number by 10 to get the Volts/turn constant say 0.8V.  Then measure how much more than the correct voltage your secondary actually is and calculate the ratio you want to reduce it, say 7%.  Then multiply your mains voltage by the reduction ratio to get 230 x 7% = 16V use this to determine the extra turns required 16V / 0.8V/T = 20 turns.

If you connect the winding in the incorrect phase your output voltage will increase instead of decrease so measure it before you connect to your electronics and swap the ends if it is a problem.

An mentioned in a comment on the other question, if you have components getting hot they may have failed earlier and caused your transformer to burn out, they may do the same for your new transformer if you do not replace them.  Large electrolytic capacitors are a known weak point in older electronic equipment.

Note also that the fuse rating is not a direct indication of the current requirement of your stereo or the mains transformer.  They are rated to be larger than normal operating and surge currents but less than expected fault currents.  You may find that your system never exceeds 2A and a 3A rated transformer is pointlessly large.

Answer (score 2):

Remove some of the secondary windings.

Comment: Thanks, I could try that if there is no other nice without modifying transformer itself.

The transformer is this one:
https://www.lemona.lt/?page=item&i_id=58238

Any tips/references how to remove the windings? And how much? I've never done that.

Comment: You can buy transformers to which you add your own secondary, which might be easier.

Comment: Or... if it's really hard to remove them then add some but wound in the oposite direction - this will subtract voltage. If one secondary turn produces 1 volt RMS then adding 2 more reverse-wound secondary turns will subtract 2 volts from 17 volts to give 15 volts. It's not too messy unless the VA of the transformer is pushed right to the limits by your load.

Comment: @Andyaka  Yours is the best solution I think as it will be working on the secondary and require a lot less  turns than adding to the primary side.  The wires will have to be rated for the secondary current but otherwise a simple modification.